# Neo4j APOC failing authentication with OSI PI JDBC

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-apoc

I'm trying to use Neo4j APOC to connect to and query data from a OSI-PI Historian using the OSI-PI JDBC driver.

I'm able to successfully load the driver using:
`CALL apoc.load.driver("com.osisoft.jdbc.Driver");`

When I run my test query, i'm getting a security error that states the credentials are invalid and that I must enter a username. A prompt then appears to allow authentication, when I enter the correct user credentials I'm given the same error.

`CALL apoc.load.jdbc("jdbc:pioledbent://[Servername]/DataSource=[Datasourcename];DCA=[filename].dca;ProtocolOrder=https/Soap:5461,NetTcp:5462;","[Table]")YIELD row
RETURN row.Name;`

[Error-Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jQDTb.png)

Comment: Do you maybe need to wrap the JDBC settings into apoc.url.encode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went in another direction with this. I configured a linked server with OSI PI OLEDB Enterprise and used the native MSSQL JDBC driver to query data.